# ECS unable to place task despite increasing instance count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm facing the following problem when creating new instances and increasing the container desired count at the same time. Since the instances are not running when I increase the desired count, I get a "service XXX was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements.". A few seconds later the new instances are up, however, the cluster still has "Desire count: 30, Pending count: 0, Running count: 3". In other words, the cluster does not "know" that there are new instances and no new containers are created.

How can I avoid this situation? Is there a parameter that instructs the cluster to monitor the instance count other than immediately after an increase in desired count?

Comment: Super interested in answers here - in my experience, you have to wait for the ECS service(s) to poll and then everything fires up. This was one of our main drivers to move to EKS - it's so much faster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case its an expected behavior of ECS, reason being that ECS service scheduler includes [circuit breaker logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-throttle-logic.html) that throttles how often tasks are placed if they repeatedly fail to launch.

> When a new container instance in spined up it takes some time to get
>   register to the Cluster and it looks like service is getting throttled
>   because time taken from increase in desired count to registration of
>   container instances to the cluster.

Having said that, if you wait for ~15 minutes after scaling number of instance in the cluster, Service scheduler will start placing the task on new container instances.

To avoid this situation, ECS Cluster should be autoscaled based on Custer reservation metric, by this ECS cluster will have additional capacity beforehand to accommodate new task count.

and here is a [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_alarm_autoscaling.html) on scaling ECS cluster.